# UIView animation doesn't get called when view is reloaded

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I have programmed the following animation for an `UIImageView` which works fine when I load the View:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         hat.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.2);
                     }completion:nil
     ];

}
```

Then I push a new View Controller on top of this view, but when I pop this new view controller, the animation doesn't fire... I've tried placing this animation code in `viewDidload` and in `viewWillAppear` but that didn't help... Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UIView Animation Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489638/ios-uiview-animation-issue)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that the UIImage view is getting unloaded? If you haven't already try setting strong/retain property to your UIImageView.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489638/ios-uiview-animation-issue